# How to properly implement the changing of an element in a container class?

Tags: c++, containers

I am building a container type which holds pointers to a class heirachy. My issue is that I can't seem to change an element using something like:

```
container[0] = x
```

Here's a minimal example that reproduces my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Animal {

protected:
    std::string noise = "None";
public:
    Animal() = default;

    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    virtual std::string getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }

};

class Duck : public Animal {
public:
    Duck() {
        noise = "Quack!";
    }
};


class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog() {
        noise = "Bark!";
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    Cat() {
        noise = "Me-thefuck-ow!";
    }

    Cat& operator=(Cat const& other) {
        noise = other.noise;
        return *this;
    }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Animal> AnimalPtr;


class AnimalsContainer {
public:
    std::vector<AnimalPtr> animals;
    AnimalPtr front;
    Duck duck;
    Dog dog;

    AnimalsContainer() {
        animals.push_back(std::make_unique<Animal>(duck));
        animals.push_back(std::make_unique<Animal>(dog));
        front = animals[0];
    }
    AnimalsContainer(AnimalsContainer& animalsContainer) = default;
    ~AnimalsContainer() = default;
    AnimalsContainer& operator=(const AnimalsContainer&  animalsContainer) = default;
    AnimalsContainer& operator=(AnimalsContainer&& animalsContainer) = default;

    AnimalPtr operator[](int index){
        return animals[index];
    }
};


int main() {
    AnimalsContainer animalsContainer;

    cout << animalsContainer[0]->getNoise() << endl;

    Cat cat;
    animalsContainer[0] = std::make_unique<Animal>(cat);

    cout << animalsContainer[0]->getNoise() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Quack!
Quack!
```

Where I want:

```
Quack!
Meow!
```

Comment: I see warnings in your code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WG5sfa

Comment: Yep, found and fixing them.

Comment: Do you want to use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`? You are mixing them now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
AnimalPtr operator[](int index) {
    return animals[index];
}
```

You return by value, then the *copy* is assigned a new value. You are supposed to return a reference:

```
AnimalPtr& operator[](int index) {
    return animals[index];
}
```

Also you probably meant to use `make_shared` instead of `make_unique` in all cases.

Comment: We'll that's subtle, would never have spotted that. Works like a charm. Thanks.